# Proper use of URLConnection and try-with-resources in Java 8

Tags: java, bufferedreader, urlconnection, try-with-resources

I am not 100% if this code is 100% save against memory leaks or leaving sockets open:

```
    public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {

        URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();

        connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(8000);

        try (InputStream is = connection.getInputStream()) {

            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            String jsonText = readAll(rd);

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);

            return json;
        }
    }

    private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        int cp;

        while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
            sb.append((char) cp);
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Would I need to put the "BufferedReader rd" into an inner second try with too, or would it be obsolete? What if a read or connection timeout occurs, and the try isn't finished yet? Why doesnt the URLConnection have a disconnect() or close() function btw?

Comment: If you do decide to put the `BufferedReader` in the try-with-resources, you can put it in the same one. Also, then you won't need to put `InputStream` in try-with-resources.

Comment: You mean like "try (BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")))) {"`? Would that be saver?

Comment: I think that both are safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All a `Reader`'s close method really does, ultimately, is close resources. (See [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#close()).) Therefore, you don't really need to close the `BufferedReader` or `InputStreamReader` if you've closed the `InputStream`. However, it is more clear that you are closing all resources, and avoids compiler warnings, if you close it anyway. Since closing a `Reader` closes all underlying `Reader`s and resources, closing the `BufferedReader` will close everything:

```
try (BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        connection.getInputStream()))) {
    return new JSONObject(readAll(rd));
}
```

So you only need to declare the top-level reader in your try-with-resources.